# Difference between mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_row?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a simple question for PHP users. The reason I couldn't get the the exact difference between `mysql_fetch_array()` and `mysql_fetch_row()` in PHP is that I had been working much with Java.

---

Before I post this question here, I got some answers from Google but I found they're somewhat confusing. Some of the links I found on the internet are as follows.

[Answer 1](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/58587.html)

[Answer 2](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/30044)

[Answer 3](http://forums.sureshkumar.net/perl-python-mysql-interview-technical-questions/16673-php-difference-between-mysql_fetch_array-mysql_fetch_row-mysql_fetch_object.html)

[Answer 4](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10349159)

---

I couldn't get the exact idea from the above answers. So actually what is the exact difference between them?

Comment: Well, the ["official documentation"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) says what?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is pretty clear on this, have you looked at it ?

```
mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows. **The type of returned array depends on
>   how result_type is defined.** By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get
>   an array with both associative and number indices. Using MYSQL_ASSOC,
>   you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), **[by] using
>   MYSQL_NUM, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works)**.

```
mysql_fetch_row ( resource $result )
```

> Returns an numerical array of strings that corresponds to the fetched
>   row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
>
> mysql_fetch_row() fetches one row of data from the result associated
>   with the specified result identifier. **The row is returned as an array.
>   Each result column is stored in an array offset, starting at offset 0.**

In summary

`mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC )` = `mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )`
`mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_NUM )` = `mysql_fetch_row( $result )`

And

`mysql_fetch_array ( $result )` = `mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )` + `mysql_fetch_row( $result )`

Comment: So what is the difference between `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` and `mysql_fetch_row()` ?

Comment: Pacerier, they are one and the same.

Comment: Personally, I read the documentation and was still  a bit confused, mostly because while they could stand independently and make sense, together they are a bit unintuitive. One would think, or at least I did, that `fetch_array()` would grab a table or several rows of data since `fetch_row()` implements the grab row functionality -- indeed, why not make `fetch_row()` the same as the current `fetch_array()`'s functionality with default NUM? Hence the confusion. Thank you for clarifying that this isnt the case.

Answer (score 62):

Many of the php programming newbies get confused about mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), mysql_fetch_assoc() and mysql_fetch_object() functions, but all of these functions performs a similar process.

Let us create a table “tb” for clear example with three fields “id”, “username” and “password”

**Table:  tb**

Insert a new row into the table with values 1 for id, tobby for username and tobby78$2 for password

[image]

**db.php**

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("tobby",$query);
?>
```

**mysql_fetch_row()**

Fetch a result row as an numeric array

```
<html>
<?php
include('db.php');
$query=mysql_query("select * from tb");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
?>
</html>
```

Result

1  tobby  tobby78$2

**mysql_fetch_object()**

Fetch a result row as an object

```
<html>
<?php
include('db.php');
$query=mysql_query("select * from tb");
$row=mysql_fetch_object($query);
echo $row->id;
echo $row->username;
echo $row->password;
?>
</html>
```

Result

1  tobby  tobby78$2

**mysql_fetch_assoc()**

Fetch a result row as an associative array

```
<html>
<?php
include('db.php');
$query=mysql_query("select * from tb");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['password'];
?>
</html>
```

Result

1  tobby  tobby78$2

**mysql_fetch_array()**

Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array and also it fetches by both associative & numeric array.

```
<html>
<?php
include('db.php');
$query=mysql_query("select * from tb");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['username'];
echo $row['password'];

<span style="color: #993300;">/* here both associative array and numeric array will work. */</span>

echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];

?>
</html>
```

Result

1  tobby  tobby78$2

Comment: The question was asked a long back, a year ago when I didn't differentiate quite properly between them. The answer is hopefully useful +1. thanks

Comment: +1 for using an example, it's the best way of explaining something

Comment: An awesome answer.

Answer (score 7):

The mysql_fetch_object{row/array/assoc}() function collects the first single matching record in its respective format and can be retrieved accordingly.

**con.php**

```
<?php
        $host     = $_GET['host'];
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $pass     = $_GET['pass'];
        $database  = $_GET['database'];
        $connect=new connect($host,$username,$pass,$database);
        class connect{
             function __construct($host,$user,$password,$db_name){
                mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Connection error");
                mysql_select_db($db_name);
                $error=mysql_error();
                if (!empty($error))
                {
                    echo $error;
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

[image]

**index.php**

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query("select * from category");
?>
```

How each value will look on dumping the array in browser

**mysql_fetch_array**

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
var_dump($row);
```

**Output:**

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  'createdBy' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  'catName' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  3 => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  'description' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

**mysql_fetch_row**

```
$row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
var_dump($row);
```

**Output:**

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  3 => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
```

**mysql_fetch_assoc**

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
var_dump($row);
```

**Output:**

```
array
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'createdBy' => string '1' (length=1)
  'catName' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  'description' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

**mysql_fetch_object**

```
$row=mysql_fetch_object($query);
var_dump($row);
```

**Output:**

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'createdBy' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'catName' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  public 'description' => string 'APTITUDE' (length=8)
  public 'status' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Rest @Gaurang has provided how to use the out for your code and other activities.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_array as the [manual says](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) can return an int (position) based index, associative array or both according to the result_type chosen.

in the other hand [mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row) always return the result set based on integer index.

I personally recommend you to use mysql_fetch_array passing MYSQL_ASSOC as second parameter since is always easier to know what field you would like to fetch

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_row returns an enumerated array, so the index are numbers. mysql_fetch_array returns an associative array (and by defaults, merge numbers for index), so, mysql_fetch_array returns, by default, all data duplicated in a single array, one set of data using number as index and another set, still in the same array, with associative index (text based indexes).

mysql_fetch_row Example:

```
Array(2)
    0 => "foo"
    1 => "bar"
```

mysql_fetch_array Example (default behavior):

```
Array(4)
    0 => "foo"
    1 => "bar"
    "user" => "foo"
    "name" => "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 functions.
    mysql_fetch_assoc
    mysql_fetch_row
    mysql_fetch_array (a combination of row and assoc)

I would recommend _assoc or _row to optimize your code and keep it clear. If you're grabbing a single column, use 
    $row = mysql_fetch_row
    $row[0]

Answer (score 1):

As the manual says: [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) can return an **associative** array depending on defaults and its second parameter (`MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM`, or `MYSQL_BOTH`).

While [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row) always returns an **indexed** array.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch row returns a numerical array for current entry

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Fetch array will by default return a full id=>key=>value array but it also offers the option of choosing either numerical or associative return

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

Answer two from the first link you provided is correct.  The comment said:

"Instead both returns all the rows from table. The 
difference between them is fetch_array return result in 
assoc array as well as numeric array and you can also 
specify which specific type of array you want by providing 
second parameter to the function while fetch_row return 
result in numeric array only."

... so using fetch_row you can't do something like

```
echo $result['name']; // can do this in fetch_array, not in fetch_row
echo $result[0]; // can do this in fetch_array and fetch_row
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql_fetch_object returns the result from the database as objects while mysql_fetch_array returns result as an array. This will allow access to the data by the field names.