# MySQL Select All Data From One Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select all of the usernames. I tried to do `SELECT username FROM members` and then `mysql_fetch_array`. So I would do `$data["username"]`. But I also want to select each row individually. Any help on how to do this would be helpful thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're trying to get an answer to. Running that SELECT statement into a while loop would supply you with each row from the database - so, what's the actual problem or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wait what? It would be able to select each if I simply loop it?

Comment: Yes - running it through while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {} would run through every row that you've selected

Comment: @auragar [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347565/difference-between-mysql-fetch-array-and-mysql-fetch-row) to find out the difference.

Comment: Basically for me the difference between how I use array and how assoc works is none. However array also works like row, in that I can use numbers instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PDO for that.Example of using **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM members");
if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['username']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: PDO? I never heard of this. Also I am not using GET data, but thank you. So where would I learn more about this PDO.

Comment: @auragar sorry i wasn't able to include the link. [So here it is](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @auragar and others. PDO and MySQLi are recommended by PHP, while mysql_* functions are deprecated. PDO has the advantage that it works with all the major databases and more, it provides prepared statements which are the default way to work for most professionals and helps prevent most if not all sql injection security holes by allowing you to separate the SQL from the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all results with `while()`

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT username FROM members');

while ($username = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $username['username']; //this will go for every result, so every row in the database
}
```

Comment: Please advise OP to stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: why is that then? mysql_ functions are not bad

Comment: @RenePot accordinmg to the manual, it is already depreciated.

Comment: exactly, mysql_functions are deprecated. It is advised to use PDO or mysqli functions instead

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['username'];
  }
```

Comment: You should advise OP to stop using `mysql_` functions.